# Poor clustered index seek performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I've got these two queries:

```
SELECT SELECT NamesRecord.NameID, NamesRecord.FulfillmentAddressID NameFulfillmentAddressID, ContractRecord.FulfillmentAddressID, ContractRecord.BillingAddressId
FROM Magnet.dbo.ContractRecord ContractRecord
    INNER JOIN Magnet.dbo.NamesRecord NamesRecord
        ON NamesRecord.NameId = ContractRecord.DonorId
WHERE NameID > -1
AND (EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Magnet.dbo.AddressRecord AddressRecord
        WHERE AddressRecord.AddressId = ContractRecord.FulfillmentAddressId
        AND BuildingFloor LIKE 'M%')
    OR  EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Magnet.dbo.AddressRecord AddressRecord
        WHERE AddressRecord.AddressId = ContractRecord.BillingAddressId
        AND BuildingFloor LIKE 'M%'))


SELECT SELECT NamesRecord.NameID, NamesRecord.FulfillmentAddressID NameFulfillmentAddressID, ContractRecord.FulfillmentAddressID, ContractRecord.BillingAddressId
FROM Magnet.dbo.ContractRecord ContractRecord
    INNER JOIN Magnet.dbo.NamesRecord NamesRecord
        ON NamesRecord.NameId = ContractRecord.DonorId
WHERE NameID > -1
AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM Magnet.dbo.AddressRecord AddressRecord
        WHERE AddressRecord.AddressId IN (ContractRecord.FulfillmentAddressId, ContractRecord.BillingAddressId)
        AND BuildingFloor LIKE 'M%'))
```

The first query runs more than 10 times faster than the second.  According to the Execution Plan, the first query uses two Clustered Index Scans with "BuildingFloor LIKE 'M%'" as the predicate, and an Index Seek on the ContractRecord for each of the sub-selects in the WHERE clause (40% cost per sub-select).

The second query uses a Clustered Index Seek with "BuildingFloor LIKE 'M%'" as the predicate, and a seek predicate for the AddressId constraints (96% cost).  It's estimated row count is completely out as well (250 actual vs 1 estimated).

How can I improve the performance of the second query?  Can I force SQL Server to choose an alternative strategy or do I have to modify the indexes on the tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per-row subqueries are slow, as are disjunctive (`or`) filter conditions. Get rid of the subqueries entirely, and if you are using an `or` predicate in a filter you might think about replacing it with a `union`. Internally, the `in` gets translated into an `or`.

```
select
    NamesRecord.NameId
from (
    select
        ContractRecord.DonorId,
        ContractRecord.FulfillmentAddressId as AddressId
    from Magnet.dbo.ContractRecord ContractRecord
    union
    select
        ContractRecord.DonorId,
        ContractRecord.BillingAddressId as AddressId
    from Magnet.dbo.ContractRecord ContractRecord
) ContractRecordInfo
join Magnet.dbo.NamesRecord NamesRecord on 1=1
    and NamesRecord.NameId = ContractRecordInfo.DonorId
    and NamesRecord.NameId > -1
join Magnet.dbo.AddressRecord AddressRecord on 1=1
    and AddressRecord.AddressId = ContractRecordInfo.AddressId
    and AddressRecord.BuildingFloor like 'M%'
```

Comment: There seems to be a difference in the returned result sets.  I'll do some more investigation before I post a follow up comment.

Comment: OK, I've found the problem and it was my fault. I didn't include a few required columns in the select statement.

Comment: It's roughly the same speed as the first query for that particular result set, but using this technique on another query dropped the execution time from 1m30s to <10s.

Comment: Well then, that's about a 10x improvement in some cases. I'm glad I could help.